# What is the easiest way to run a one time couchbase query?

Tags: couchbase

I need to run a one time query on the whole dataset in couchbase (like calculate an average value for some field for a report).

I built a developer view with the map/reduce I need. Now if I try to run it on the whole dataset in production (`&full_set=true`) it gives me an empty result and goes into some indexing process that looks like is getting reset after every record update, after a few hours it was still somewhere around 1% so I just gave up. The bucket is not that big (under 1m records) but is updated often.

Making a new view for a one time query seems to be an overkill, is there a quick and easy alternative?

Comment: Did you actually promote that view to be a production view? If not, it will never see the full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it ran into a problem when running over the full data set.  Is there anything interesting in the mapreduce_errors.log?  [See the docs](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/Trbl-logs.html) for more info on where to find them.